# How to map a one-to-one relationship on one side of a many-to-many relationship with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm

I'm mapping an existing database to SQLAlchemy. My database includes a many-to-many relationship via an association table. To perhaps slightly complicate things further, one side of the many-to-many is polymorphic. There is a fourth table with a one-to-one relationship to a model of the polymorphic association. I'd like to create a direct relationship from the far left of my many-to-many to the fourth table on the right side of my one-to-one.

Here is a simplified diagram of my SQLAlchemy models:
[image: ERD with 4 tables]

I am able to access `products` via the `product_chain` attribute: `chain.product_chain.products`.
How can I declare a relationship in `Chain` so I can access `products` directly? Like: `chain.products`

So far I've tried to use the `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin` arguments.
Here's my model in SQLAlchemy:

```py
class Chain(Base):
    __tablename__ = "chain"

    chain_id: Mapped[String] = mapped_column(
        "chain_id", String, primary_key=True
    )

    product_chain: Mapped["ProductChain"] = relationship(
        "ProductChain", back_populates="chain"
    )

    # This relationship doesn't work
    products: Mapped[list["Product"]] = relationship(
        secondary=product_category_association,
        primaryjoin="Chain.chain_id == ProductChain.chain_id",
        back_populates="categories",
    )


product_category_association = Table(
    "product_category_association",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("product_id", ForeignKey("products.product_id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("category_id", ForeignKey("product_category.category_id"), primary_key=True),
)


class ProductCategory(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product_category"

    category_id: Mapped[Integer] = mapped_column(
        "category_id", Integer, primary_key=True
    )
    category_name: Mapped[String] = mapped_column("category_name", String)
    category_type: Mapped[String] = mapped_column("category_type", String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_on": category_type,
        "polymorphic_identity": "category",
    }


class ProductChain(ProductCategory):
    chain_id: Mapped[String] = mapped_column("chain_id", ForeignKey("chain.chain_id"), nullable=True)

    chain: Mapped["Chain"] = relationship("Chain", back_populates="product_chain")

    products: Mapped[list["Product"]] = relationship(secondary=product_category_association, back_populates="product_chains")

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "chain"}


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product"

    product_id: Mapped[String] = mapped_column("product_id", String, primary_key=True)

    product_chains: Mapped[list["ProductChain"]] = relationship(
        secondary=product_category_association,
        back_populates="products",
    )

    # This relationship doesn't work
    chains: Mapped[list["Chain"]] = relationship(
        secondary=product_category_association,
        secondaryjoin="ProductChain.chain_id == Chain.chain_id",
        back_populates="products",
    )
```

When called this code returns the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper[Product(products)]'. Original exception was: Could not locate any simp
le equality expressions involving locally mapped foreign key columns for secondary join condition 'product_categories.chain_id = chain.chain_id' on relationship Product.chains.
```

Once again, how can I declare a relationship in `Chain` so I can access `products` directly from a `Chain` object?